# how does lambda pick values to return

Tags: python, lambda

In a tutorial, I see a piece of code that I verified works:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

```
>>> student_tuples = [
        ('john', 'A', 15),
        ('jane', 'B', 12),
        ('dave', 'B', 10),
]
>>> sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])   # sort by age
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

Why is the student[2] known by python to refer to the third element of each tuple? Why didn't it try to sort by the third tuple, instead of the third item of each tuple?

Comment: because it iterates over the iterable passing each subelement, on a side note `operator.itemgetter(2)` would be more efficeint

Comment: why is that, does that one run faster?

Comment: yes  itemgetter is done at the c level, a lambda is more expensive, it depends on what you want to do as there are some things you can do with a lambda that itemgetter cannot do but for your example itemgetter would be more efficeint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `sorted` function sends the elements of its iterable argument to lambda function.and in this case the tuples will be sent to `lambda`.

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from **each list element**: key=str.lower. The default value is None (compare the elements directly).

Comment: so that's why key has to take a function

Comment: @codyc4321 Indeed, you want to sort the elements not the list ;)